# Button not getting styled in PyGI

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I am trying to create a button that is red instead of the default colour. I am applying the style through a `CssProvider()` but the button's colour does not change. What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

CSS = """
GtkButton {
    background-color: red;
}
"""

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Theme")
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        cssprovider = Gtk.CssProvider()
        cssprovider.load_from_data(CSS)

        screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
        sc = Gtk.StyleContext()
        sc.add_provider_for_screen(screen, cssprovider,
                Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

        btn = Gtk.Button(label="Click")
        self.add(btn)

win = MyWindow()
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: It's possibly a bug. Changing the CSS to "background: red" fixes this for me. On other widgets, both background and background-color seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is background-image takes precedence over background-color, the former is most likely already set in the theme (button gradient). You can force a complete replacement of the background using the "background" property or by using "background-color" along with un-setting "background-image":

```
GtkButton {
    background: red;
}
```

or:

```
GtkButton {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

See: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=728027